# Ruby on Rails and SendGrid; dynamic template data is not populating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and SendGrid.

I cannot figure out why the code sample below does not work? It does send an email using the correct template, but the dynamic data does not fill in. Any input/insight is appreciated.

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

mail = SendGrid::Mail.new
mail.template_id = 'template id'
mail.from = Email.new(
  email: 'someone@somewhere.com',
  name: 'ABC')

personalization = SendGrid::Personalization.new
personalization.add_to(Email.new(email: 'someone@somewhere.com', name: 'ABC'))
personalization.add_dynamic_template_data(
  'variable' => [
    { 'first_name' => 'John' },
    { 'last_name' => 'Doe' },
    { 'email' => 'john@doe.com' },
    { 'message' => 'The message is as follows' }
  ]
)

mail.add_personalization(personalization)

sgp = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['sendgrid_api_key'])
response = sgp.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
```

The template code looks like the following.

```
Hello from {{first_name}} {{last_name}}.
{{message}}
```

And the result ends up without the variable values filled in.

```
Hello from .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The dynamic data that you are adding is more complicated than the template. Instead of sending an array of hashes as the dynamic data, you can just send a hash. Try this instead:

```rb
personalization.add_dynamic_template_data({
  'first_name' => 'John',
  'last_name' => 'Doe',
  'email' => 'john@doe.com',
  'message' => 'The message is as follows'
})
```

See [this example in the SendGrid Ruby library docs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/main/use-cases/transactional-templates.md#with-mail-helper-class) too.

Comment: **That worked!** Thank you so much for your answer! I was looking at this source code example [Sendgrid Git](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/main/examples/helpers/mail/example.rb#L21). The code I was using is at the very bottom. Thank you for helping me with that. Appreciated.